# There is no significant lags in ACF and PACF models

Tags: time-series, acf-pacf

How to interpret this? How to determine the number of lags?[AC Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNq3B.jpg)[image: PAC Plot]

Comment: The situation on acf plot is quite similar

Comment: Perhaps there is not substantial auto correlation

Answer (score 1):

The PACF here shows no significant lags. Every lag is within the confidence intervals. You also mentioned that ACF shows similar results.

Based on this, you probably don't need to include any lags (either AR or MA lags) because there is no autocorrelation.

Comment: Right, and this is the white noise model a.k.a. ARIMA(0,0,0).